# What are the steps to function design?

Tags: functions, polynomials, recreational-mathematics

So I'm trying to write a program, and I want to use math functions to help it. In this example, I'm trying to change the color of a line based on the position of each pixel on the line.

Anyway, I wanted to make a function with certain aspects, and I have no idea how to go about doing it. For this function, I wanted it to have:

1. A global maximum at (0, 1)
2. A horizontal asymptote on the x axis
3. Symmetric over the y axis
4. And for it to dip below the x axis before approaching the asymptote

Just thinking about it, I figured I needed a couple things, like it should be something like x^4, since it has 3 extremes, and it probably needs to be a rational function since it has an asymptote. But I don't know how to go any further than that, without guessing and checking to an extreme (I tried that, it didn't work out well). I just wanted to know what sorts of things people do to design a function. I figure you start with picking the type of function (polynomial, logistic, exponential, etc.) and there will be different steps for each, but I don't really know what to do past that.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: First of all, what do want the domain and range of your function to be? It sounds like you want a function from the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or maybe 3-space,$\mathbb{R}^3$) to the reals $\mathbb{R}$. Is that right?

Comment: @RobArthan Yeah, I do want it to be R^2, not R^3, and domain to be all reals. Range should be something like [w, 1]. Where w is some number -1<w<0. Just to give a concrete number, I'd go with .25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've had a little calculus, you could start by describing the derivative.  If you want the function to have a global max at $x=0$, then $f^{\prime}(x)=x \cdot g(x)$, so that when you plug in $x=0$ you get $0$ in the derivative (the $g(x)$ is just short-hand for "something else in addition").  To make it symmetric about the $y$-axis, just make sure you have an even function.  If you want a horizontal asymptote, then you cannot simply have a polynomial.  You could have a fraction of polynomials (if the largest power in the denominator is bigger than the largest power on top, you'll have horizontal asymptotes being the $x$-axis).  Making sure it dips below the axis is trickier, but one way you could do it is to have local minima at $x=\pm 1$.  To do this add $(x-1)(x+1)$ into the derivative.  When you integrate, you'll get a constant of integration.  To make sure that you hit $(0, 1)$ you can multiply your function by a constant to adjust heights (this works provided that, before adjusting, the $y$-value isn't 0).

All that said, one example that comes to mind (is not quite what I described above), but try $f(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+1}$.  At $x=0$ you hit $y=1$, the function is even--so it is symmetric.  And it bounces above and below the $x$-axis but has $y=0$ as a horizontal asymptote.

Comment: This was really helpful, I didn't think about using the derivative. I'll probably mess around more with that new info in the morning and see what I can come up with. Thank you.

Comment: @awenonian, the derivative is a really easy way to do it provided that you don't have the asymptote condition (if you just want to specify maxima/minima and points on the curve).  If you make the derivative a fraction, it can be tricky to integrate, and tricky to guarantee you get an even function in the end.